# why does gradientdrawable.setBackground makes my app crash?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, gradientdrawable

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
        drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
        drawable.setStroke(3, Color.GREEN);

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.primary, container, false);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout ) view.findViewById(R.layout.primary);
        // 1 layout.setBackground(fragmentBorder); <----
                // ^ above line causes the crash ^

        layout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable); 
        return view; 
    }
```

Theres no compilation error, it just crashes when I test drive it

Comment: please post what error you getting?

Comment: I put this on onCreateView

Comment: put your error log

Comment: `findViewById(R.layout.primary)` - That is returning null, because `R.layout.primary` is not an ID. You need an `R.id` there. Or, if the root `View` in the `primary` layout is that `LinearLayout` you want, then you can just cast the inflated `View` to it - `LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view;`.

Comment: Omg cant believe responses so fast.. it solved my problem.. how do I accept it as an answer

Comment: You can just accept Lokesh's answer, if you like, if that's what solved your problem. Cheers!

Comment: Im new to this and to android, this is amazing.. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout ) view.findViewById(R.layout.primary);
```

Please change above line as

```
 LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout ) view.findViewById(R.id.primary);
```

your linear layout remain null that's why it crashing

Comment: i think some one already commented that..check mike's comment